# Recover data from a Django Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

It's my first time doing a Django Form challenge.
The challenge for now is just from a HTML Template get the *last_name* information and store into DB from views. So I have a scenario below:

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

an HTML template, I will put below only the form part:

```
      <form action="{% url 'store' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="last_name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Last Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Last Name</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

And the views.py itself... I created a InsertLastName ModelForm to store the data from the form, but didn't work. For some reason, when I tryed to call form.cleaned_data I reveived an error about the is_valid() verification. Seens like that I'm not getting the information from label.

```
class InsertLastName(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

        fields = ['last_name']
        exclude = ['first_name']

def index(request):
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    context = {'persons': persons}
    return render(request, '/index.html', context)

def store(request):
    form = InsertLastName(request.POST or None)
    print(form.cleaned_data['last_name'])

    return HttpResponse("Storing a new Last Name object into storage")
```

What is the correct way to get the information from *last_name* label in my form?
I'm following that [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) and coding from a challenge template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your just set attr name for your input html tag
Example:

```
<input type="text" name="first">
```

And for get input in function store in view.py:

```
request.POST.get("first")
```

Add this to your html template in your form

```
{{persons}}
```

Comment: Already did, take a look at my HTML... but if i remove the validation of is_valid from my views.py I received a error: 'Person' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: please see new post edit

Comment: I wrote a print(request.POST.get("last_name")) but it returned "None"... again seems like it's not getting the information from input

Comment: You not use your form django in your html

Comment: Worked! It was a miss typing... tks a lot